# In Swift, is there a way to programmatically add subviews that I can use throughout my class without having optional attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, standards, option-type

Typically, when I create custom views with their own subviews, it tends to look something like this:

```
class MyView : UIView {

    var myButton : UIButton?
    var myLabel  : UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //Create the frames and such

        myButton = UIButton(frame: myButtonsFrame)
        myLabel  = UILabel(frame: myLabelsFrame)
    }

    // Do other things
}
```

This technically works, but it seems to violate the whole concept of optionals in Swift. Because my subviews are *always* created, then they should not have `?`s.

But, because they do, I'm constantly forced to check if they're nil or force unwrap even though I know they should never be and if they were, they should fail in the init.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply switch the code around:

```
class MyView : UIView {

    var myButton : UIButton
    var myLabel  : UILabel

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        myButton = UIButton(frame: myButtonsFrame)
        myLabel  = UILabel(frame: myLabelsFrame)

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    // Do other things
}
```

You simply have to make sure all stored properties are initialized before calling `super.init`.

Alternatively you could declare the properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals like `UILabel!` and `UIButton!` if you make 100% sure that they have values set before the very first time you try to access any property or function on them.

Note that what @tmpz said in the comment is true - you might want to declare the properties as a constant using `let` instead of `var` if you do not plan on changing their values after the `init` ever.

Comment: Use let if you don't play to re-assign the variables.

Comment: So what if I want to create my subviews via a function? Example: `myButton = getUIButton()`

Comment: @FlaqueDeau as long as that function is not on the same object, that is not a problem - if the function is a member function of `MyView` you are out of luck with the first option and have to go with the second one.

Comment: So then is the only way to create my subviews without having a really long init function is to create separate objects that create the view's subviews?

Comment: @FlaqueDeau Kind of - the alternative is to use for example a `class Helper { class func getUIButton() -> UIButton {...} }`